# How to trigger else clause in an onload event?

Tags: javascript

I have the `Comments` handle in my Google App Engine app to display the comments. I want to stop the page from loading if the user (defined as "chooser" here) is not in `localStorage`.

I get the first 2 alerts: `"load event"` and `chooser: "undefined"`. Since "chooser" is undefined I expect the else clause to trigger but I don't get the alert in else clause.

Also, the first item in ordered list is displayed but not the rest. So I assume there is an issue with loading of the page. How can I fix this?

```
class Comments(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Choices</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function showChoices ()

{ 

  alert("load event"); 
  var chooser = localStorage.getItem("chooser"); 
  alert("chooser: " + chooser);

  if (chooser) 
  { 
    document.getElementById("topten").style.display="inline"; 
  }
  else 
  { 
    alert("else triggers"); 
    document.write("get an invitation"); 
  } 
}

  window.onload = showChoices;

      </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="content">""")

        #python code:
        query = Users.all()
        e = query.fetch(10)
        self.response.out.write("""<ol>""")
        for item in e:
            self.response.out.write("""
            <div id="topten" class="title" style="display:none">

                <li>%s (<span class="small">%s</span>)</li>

            </div>
            <hr><br />""" 
            % tuple([item.choice, item.owner]))
        self.response.out.write("""</ol>""")
        self.response.out.write("""
    </div>

  </body>
</html>""")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that chooser is undefined and not the string literal "undefined"?

see [this fiddle i made](http://jsfiddle.net/4cgsN/)

Comment: you are right. I cleared localStorage once again and now I get `chooser: null` and else is triggered.

Comment: Glad it worked. Just for the future, I would recommend always using `===` when working with weak-typed languages like JavaScript.

Comment: any suggestions what might happened to have "undefined" in localStorage? Thanks.

Comment: You might have saved a variable that was undefined. It would have been converted to a string. Just check your variables before you save them with something like `testVar!=undefined && testVar !== NULL`. See how you may have created the string "undefined" from an undefined variable here: http://jsfiddle.net/FBWtY/